# How to open a layout whith setOnClickListener

Tags: android, button, android-activity, layout, click

I have an Activity that open others which each other open a layaout, is it posible my first activity to open the layout (with the touch of buton) whithout the existance of the others activitys?

Activity1.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.button1); // Αναζητούμε τα στοιχεία του κουμπιού
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);// Πατώντας το button1 ανοίγει μία νέα δραστηριότητα
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    Button button15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    Button button16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
    Button button_end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_end);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_5.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_6.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_7.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_8.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_9.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_10.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_11.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_12.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_13.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_14.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_15.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Photo_16.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is one of the in-between activities

Activity_Photo1.java

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity_Photo_1 extends Activity {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_1);
    }
}
```

and this is one of the layouts

photo1.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFCC0000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFCC0000">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/button1_1"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by without existence of the others activitys?

Comment: your Question is not clear. please edit you question

Comment: if you want to open another class without use of setonclicklistner then u can use fragment

Comment: call the `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);` wherever you want to load another layout. but be sure that after loading another layout,your previous views will be under `NP exception`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct then try this piece of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```